# Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ then $\bar{A} \subseteq \bar{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ then $\bar{A} \subseteq \bar{B}$, where $\bar{A}, \bar{B}$ denotes the closure of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

- If $\bar{A} = \emptyset$, then we already obtain our desired result.
- Assume $\bar{A} \neq \emptyset$.

Since $\bar{A} = A \cup A^\prime \neq \emptyset$, where $A^\prime$ denotes the accumulation point(s) of $A$, we must have that $A \neq \emptyset$, since if $A = \emptyset$ then $A^\prime = \emptyset$ and hence $\bar{A} = \emptyset$, which we already showed in our first case.

Hence we know $\exists x \in A \implies x \in B$ and hence $B \neq \emptyset$.

Can anyone please tell me if I am on the right track and provide me with some HINTS as to how I can go about completing this proof?

NOTE: This proof comes before we have used sequences and limits/limit points for accumulation points

Comment: Write down the definition of an accumulation point. Assume $x\in \bar{A}$. Then you need to show that $x \in \bar{B}$

Comment: Things would be trivialized if you already knew (well, maybe you do?) that $\overline A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x \in \bar{A}$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in B \subset \bar B$. Assume $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$. Then every open set (in the underlying topology) that contains $x$ also contains a point in $A$. Since $A\subset B$ these points (in the open sets that contain $x$) also show that $x \in \bar B$.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, we take the "closure" to be defined as $\bar{C}=\bigcap\{S\supseteq C\mid S\text{ is close}\}$. Then for $A\subseteq B$, we have $\bar{A}\subseteq\bar{B}$, since for every close $S$ containing $B$, $S$ also contains $A$. More precisely, that is $\{S\supseteq A\mid S\text{ is close}\}\supseteq\{S\supseteq B\mid S\text{ is close}\}$, and hence $\bigcap\{S\supseteq A\mid S\text{ is close}\}\subseteq\bigcap\{S\supseteq B\mid S\text{ is close}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

by the definition of $\bar{A}$..if $A \subset Y$ s.t $Y$ is closed in $X$ then $\bar{A} \subset Y$...in other word MINIMUM CLOSED SET containning A is $\bar{A}$...now $ A \subset B \subset \bar{B}$ and $\bar{B}$ is closed...so $\bar{A} \subset \bar{B}$